# How to specify custom libc++

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

I have built libc++ and want to use it when compiling my program ?
so I have something like

```
clang++ -stdlib=~/libc++/libc++.so main.cpp
```

but this does not work. How can use my custom built libc++ when building the application?

Comment: Have you tried using a absolute path? (`~` is not absolute). Also, specify what does not work? Do you have an error message?

Comment: I've tried with absolute path as well, Clang says: "invalid library in argument -stdlib=~/libc++/libc++.so"

Comment: Please update your question, do not post it as a comment :)

Comment: The `-stdlib=~/libc++/libc++.so` argument is invalid. Clang accepts `-stdlib=libc++`, and you have to add the library to your `PATH`. See [this](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html) for more details.

Comment: But I already have the default libc++, will it override it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This information comes from [llvm documentation about libcxx](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html).

If you want to use a custom libc++ with clang you have to specify argument like this  :

`$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++ -I<path_to_libcxx>/include/c++/v1 -L<path_to_libcxx>/lib -Wl,-rpath,<path_to_libcxx>/lib main.cpp ${end_of_compile_line...}`

Alternatively, you can put the path of your library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (assuming you are under Linux) :

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<libcxx-install-prefix>/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

and compile using simply these options :

`$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++ -I<path_to_libcxx>/include/c++/v1 -L<path_to_libcxx>/lib  main.cpp -o ${end_of_compile_line...}`