# Clang does not find basic header files

Tags: c++, clang

My clang does not find basic header files like `<algorithm>`. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823/clang-doesnt-see-basic-headers) I have to install the `libstdc++` via `yum install gcc-c++`. On my machine `libstdc++` is already present but in a different folder. How can I tell clang to search in that folder?

**Clang output:**

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib64/clang/6.0.1/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
throughput_benchmark.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
#include <algorithm>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Some of the dirs:**

```
find / -name "libstdc++*"
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
/etc/alternatives/libstdc++.so
```

I am using `clang version 6.0.1` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).

When passing custom include paths, I seem to be able to compile, but I get linker command failed with

> exit code 1 (cannot find crtbegin.o),

even though that is included in one of the custom include paths and the are also included with `-L/path/to/lib`.

Comment: You are missing STL. Have you installed `gcc-c++` as one of the answers suggests? (yes, it will also install `gcc`)

Comment: @TomTrebicky isnt that what I did when running `yum install gcc-c++`?

Comment: Oh boy, of course, I guess I can't read. Try to confirm the file is there `find /usr/include/ -type f -name "algorithm"`. When you do, pass the directory to `clang` using the include directive `-I/path/to/algorithm`.

Comment: @TomTrebicky The STL has been obsolete for decades. You mean the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Have you closed and reopened your shell? You may have new path variables after installing libstdc++. Though I'm not entirely sure how that works.

Comment: Some workaround ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20530105/4386278) if you're still stuck

Comment: The linker needs custom library paths, not include paths.